# Creating tables in InfluxDB via Terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, centos, influxdb

Are there tutorials online that teaches you how to create tables and input values in InfluxDB? How would you create a table and insert values into them?

Comment: Why did I receive a thumbs down?

Comment: Upvoted this one. Questions must not be downvoted because the documentation on a framework is poor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

InfluxDB doesn't really have the concept of a table. Data is structured into series, which is composed of measurements, tags, and fields.

Measurements are like buckets.

Tags are indexed values.

Fields are the actual data.

Data is written into InfluxDB via line protocol. The structure of line protocol is as follows

```
<measurement>,<tag>[,<tags>] <field>[,<field>] <timestamp>
```

An example of a point in line protocol:

```
weather,location=us-midwest temperature=82 1465839830100400200
```

To insert data into the database you'll need to issue an HTTP POST request to the `/write` endpoint, specifying the `db` query parameter.

For example:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb --data-binary "weather,location=us-midwest temperature=82 1465839830100400200"
```

For more information see the [Getting Started](http://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/introduction/getting_started/) section of the InfluxDB docs.

Comment: additionally as the get-started says: you can use an insert statement with the CLI, such as this: INSERT weather,location=us-midwest temperature=82 1465839830100400200

Comment: And just to be clear, "<measurement>" in the above example really means measurement type (although the "weather" "measurement" (type) value in the above example is really more of a category of measurement types, maybe not the best example).

I think a better teaching example for a data row might be (intentionally verbose for teaching):

'temperature_measurement,location=us-midwest temperature_value=82 1465839830100400200'

Answer (score 14):

I just want to [quote](https://community.influxdata.com/t/best-practices-around-database-retention-policy-measurement-design/1147/2) the moderator of the [influxdata community](http://community.influxdata.com) here:

> You can think of
>
> - *measurements* as **tables** in SQL,
> - *tags* as indexed columns,
> - and *fields* as unindexed columns

Comment: And "tag keys" are the names of the indexed columns, "tag values" are the values for a tag column with a given tag key (index column name).   Field "keys" (also called field "names") are the names of unindexed columns and field values are the values of the respective unindexed column.   Note, you can only used tag key/name & tag values in "show measurements" commands (a "measurement" (in the influx sense of the word) is table holding rows where the rows are the actual data measurements (in the english sense of the word))

Answer (score 6):

Also, there is no "create table" statement.  Just insert to a table.   The web call was specified above.   If you have the "influx" command line interpreter, you can do:

```
export INFLUX_PASSWORD="BlahBlahBlah"
influx -host <hostname> -u <username> -d <database>
insert my_influx_test_measurement,index1="aaa" value1="bbb"
```

Note that "insert" is only a command line (aka "influx") thing.  Doesn't work with http calls.

It's to bad they named the command line interpreter "influx".  Now when anyone refers to "influx", it's not clear if it's the database or the CLI.